# REST API token authentication

Tags: c#, api, rest, aes, token

I just started a development of my first REST API in .NET. Since it will be stateless I will use tokens for authentication:

**Basic idea (System.Security.Cryptography):**

- AES for encryption + HMACSHA256 for integrity
- token data will consist object with properties: username, date of issuing and timeout
- database will hold username, hashed password and HMAC hash

**Login:**

- check if credentials are valid (username, compare hashed password to db value)
- if true, encrypt data object
- use HMAC on generated token and store it to database
- return token (without HMAC) to user (cookie/string)

**Request to method which requires authentication:**

- user sends token with each request
- token is decrypted
- if it is expired, error
- if not expired use HMAC and compare username + generated hash with db values
- if db check valid, user is authenticated

**The way I see it, this approach has following pros:**

- even if db is comprosmised, it does not contain actual token (hash cannot be reversed...)
- even if attacker has token, he cannot increase expiration by updating fields since expiration date is in the token itself

Now firstly, I wonder if this is good approach at all.

Besides that I still didn't figure out, where to store AES and SHA256 keys on server (should i just hardcode them? If I put them into web.config or use machine key than I have a problem in case of load balanced servers,...).

And lastly where do I store AES IV vectors, since Crypto.CreateEncryptor requires it for decryption? Does it mean that users have to send token + IV with each request?

I hope this makes any sense and I thank you for answers in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, now I did some more research and came down with this solution:

- token will contain originally specified data (username, date of issuing and timeout)
- token is generated with [encrypt-then-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366194/637900) (it includes AES encrypted data, IV vector + tag of these 2 values for authentication, generated with HMACSHA265)
- token tag will be written to db
- user will be authenticated if:

  - tag is valid (token authentication)
  - data can be decrypted
  - token has not expired yet
  - tag matches the one written in database
  - user is not blocked in database (token invalidation on demand)
- keys will be stored in web.config separate section. Same keys will have to be on every server (per application of course)

I didn't use FormsAuthenticationTicket because in .NET there are following issues:

- same keys are used for different purposes (machinekey for view states, resources and formauthtickets)
- mac-then-encrypt, used by .NET is not considered [as safe as encrypt-then-mac](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac)
- no built in way to [invalidate token before it is expired](http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2012/04/05/forms-authentication-remember-me-its-hard-not-too?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter)

Comment: I'm curious, why store data inside the token? If you have to validate it against the db, then why not store the data in the db and simply use a Guid or other random token?

Comment: Because of token expiration date - I wanted to make sure it cannot be updated in database + you dont have to make a db query if it is expired anyway.

Comment: You should check out OAuth (http://oauth.net/), since that's basically what you are describing here.

Comment: @MikeCaron, thank you for your comment. Do you maybe have a good sample for how to implement it for custom users repositry (what has to be done in order support functionalities I am trying to implement with my own logic)? I dont want to support access to my API with Twitter, FB, etc. accounts. Users will have to register.

Comment: @PavleGartner Look at it from the perspective of the service: You can pick your authority, and the client will have to use those credentials. If you want that authority to be your own database, that's fine. Just do the validation yourself!

Comment: @MikeCaron thanks again for anwser. So I presume authentication would be handled by OAuth (credentials from Gmail, FB, etc.) and authorization (Roles etc.) can be by application specifics?

Comment: OAuth is not a service, it's a protocol. This comment box is not really sufficient to explain the nuances, so I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a follow up from the comment thread under the question.

You seem to be a bit confused as to what, exactly, OAuth is, so hopefully I can clarify it here.

OAuth is not a web service or something you consume. It is a protocol that describes the way that a site can authenticate a user against a service, without allowing the site to know what the user's credentials are. As a side benefit, most OAuth providers also have a web service to query the user's information, and permission to do so can be granted at the same time.

Typically, you are interested in implementing OAuth from the perspective of the site (eg, AcmeWidgets.com) so that a user can log in via Facebook or Google or something. However, you can also implement the service side (eg, where Facebook normally would be), and allow others to authenticate against YOU.

So, for example, let's say you have a web service to allow for third-party sites to provision Acme-brand Widgets for users. Your first third-party implementor is the popular MyBook.org. The flow would look something like this:

1. Someone invites the User to use the "Acme Widgets" app on their MyBook profile.
2. The user clicks on the button, which redirects to AcmeWidgets.com. The URL looks something like:

   `http://acmewidgets.com/oauth/user?r=http%3A%2F%2Fmybook.org%2Foauth%2Fclient&appid=12345`
3. The user is asked if they want to allow MyBook to access their data and provision widgets.
4. The user clicks Yes, whereupon Acme Widgets notes that the user has allowed it.
5. The user is redirected back to MyBook, at a URL like this:

   `http://mybook.org/oauth/client?token=ABCDEFG`
6. MyBook, on the server side, now takes that token, and places a web service call BACK to AcmeWidgets:

   `http://acmewidgets.com/oauth/validate?token=ABCDEFG&appid=12345&appsecret=67890`
7. AcmeWidgets replies with the final authentication token identifying the user.
8. Alternately, it fails, which means the user is trying to fake a token, or they denied permission or some other failure condition.
9. MyBook, with the token, can now call AcmeWidgets APIs:

   `http://acmewidgets.com/api/provision?appid=12345&token=ABC123&type=etc`

This is all known as the OAuth dance. Note that there are a number of implementation defined things here, like URLs, the means of encoding the various tokens, whether tokens can expire or be revoked, etc.

Hopefully that clears everything up for you!

Comment: Thanks, really nicely explained

Comment: First place in the web, where I found OAuth protocol described clearly and shortly!